# How to sort lines with Slickgrid?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I'm using [Slickgrid](http://wiki.github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/) but I'd prefer not to use `slick.model.js`. How can I write `grid.onSort` to sort the lines of my data set?

My code uses the standard template:

```
 $(function() {
        var data = [ ... ];
        grid = new Slick.Grid($("#myGrid"), data, columns, options);
        grid.onSort = function(sortCol, sortAsc) {
         sortdir = sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
         sortcol = sortCol.field;
         // ?? 
     };
 })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own comparer to sort "data" with (see standard Array sorting examples).
After that, tell the grid to rerender:

```
grid.invalidate();
grid.render();
```